# Angular ngClass boolean dont detection

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ng-class

I have an icon "fa-duotone fa-rotate-right", and I want when changing "loading = true", the class "fa-spin" is added, everything works ok, but when it becomes "false" it does not stop, I’m a beginner in Angular, don’t discuss much, maybe you know how you can decide or tell me. Thanks

Html

```html
 <button mat-fab color="primary" class="float-end"  (click)="load()">
     <mat-icon class="fa-duotone fa-rotate-right" [ngClass]="loading  ? 'fa-spin' : ''"></mat-icon>
 </button>
```

Typescript

```
  load(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.products);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.loading = false;
        this.selection.clear();
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.error('Server error in Getting Products');
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Reading [the documentation for `ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) would go a long way toward answering this question...

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for `ngClass` is not correct. Try this:

```html
<mat-icon 
  class="fa-duotone fa-rotate-right"
  [ngClass]="{'fa-spin': loading}"
>
</mat-icon>
```

Comment: It does not work, the icon continues to spin (animation), that is, at first it is true, then when it becomes false it should stop, but the animation continues to work anyway.

Comment: Are you completely sure that you are getting success response from the server? Maybe you are getting error, and you don't set `loading` to false in the error handler.

Comment: I need fa-spin to work somehow asynchronously, at first it is always true, but after a few seconds when I get a response from the back-end, it becomes false, but the class inside the icon still remains

Comment: There are no errors, since I receive products from the backend and successfully show in the table

Comment: Wait.... I am not sure, but can you try to remove `fa-rotate-right` class? Maybe that class is also adding spinner. And that class is always present.

Comment: no, that's the name of the icon

Comment: animation only "fa-spin" adds

Answer (score 0):

In your exemple, the sintax of the [ngClass] it's wrong. Change to this:

```
<button mat-fab color="primary" class="float-end" (click)="load()">
    <mat-icon class="fa-duotone fa-rotate-right" [ngClass]="{'fa-spin': loading}"></mat-icon>
</button>
```

I did this change and is working, probly your problem is that the your query returning a error, and than try set "loading = false" inside error code:

```
 load(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.products);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.loading = false;
        this.selection.clear();
      },
      error => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.alertService.error('Server error in Getting Products');
      }
    );
  }
```

Good luck :)